# Creating a database via JDBC API

Tags: java, jdbc

First off I am a newbie when it comes to programming.I have an assignment due in a few days, where I am supposed to create  database of animals to demonstrate the uses of the JDBC API. this is the exact requirements of the assignment:

> Write a Java program (non-GUI preferred) to demonstrate the use of
>   JDBC.
>
> The program should allow a user to do the following:
>
> •Write a list of animal and its characteristics to a database using
>   JDBC
>  •Display the characteristics of an animal when that animal is
>   selected.

Now, I have been pouring over my textbooks reading all the sections on databases and trying to follow the examples set forth to finish this assignment and I am stuck.

I keep getting a `no suitable driver found error for the database URL`.

I have followed the examples, altering them in the areas needed to reflect the assignment and it still does not work.

I enter the examples exactly as they are written, and they will not compile. I have been looking throughout the Internet trying to figure this out and , honestly, I don't get it.

I am using the NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 if that makes a difference.

Here is the code I have so far. I know that I don't have the display methods in yet or the information in the database table but that is beside the point if I can't even get it to implement the database.

I am also getting an "Unclosed String Literal" message in the IDE on line 15. That line is written ESCATLY as my textbooks show it.

```
package animalsweek4;
import java.sql.*;


public class AnimalsWeek4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        try{
            final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:Animals; create = true";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            s.execute(CREATE TABLE Animals ( "+
            "Name Char(10)"+
            "Type Char(10)"+
            "Diet Char (10)"+
            "Habitat Char 10)");
            s.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error"+ ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to include the JDBC driver (for Derby in your case) in the classpath when the program is executed. You example won't compile either

Comment: In Netbeans, you can include the JDBC driver Jar file by right clicking the "Libraries" node in your project and selecting `Add Jar/Folder` and browsing to where ever the Jar is (you will need to download it)

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the [Apache Derby: Quick Start](https://db.apache.org/derby/quick_start.html).

Comment: s.execute(" you are missing this double quote. I think you will (eventually) find that your sql syntax needs some more work.

Comment: IMHO DB_URL value should be `"jdbc:derby:Animals;create=true"` (**no space symbol**).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the driver not found error because you might not have added the derby drivers to the program library. In your program, right click on the libraries folder and select add jar/Folder and add the derby jar files (You should have derby jar files with you in your local system). Or download from internet or ask your friends for that.

Coming to the code, Your SQL is wrong. So i have done some modifications to your code and its working fine in my system. After the drivers are added, you can run the code.

```
import java.sql.*;


public class AnimalsWeek4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        Connection conn=null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        String createTableSQL="CREATE TABLE  Animals (Name VARCHAR(10),Type VARCHAR(10),Diet VARCHAR(10),Habitat VARCHAR(10))";
        try{
            final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:Animals;create = true";
            //final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Animals");
            s.close();
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(createTableSQL);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Table is created!");

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error"+ ex.getMessage());
        }finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Also you should create a database and run a server initially in your local.Then only you can access a DB and then add a table to DB.

Comment: Thank you for the info everyone.  I'm going to give this a shot and see what I can do.

Comment: create table String is un-closed (has coma `,` but not `)` ) at the end. If derby accept such, I'm surprised.

Comment: pls add NEXT parenthesis   `+"Habitat VARCHAR(10) )");`

Comment: why You write "is working in my system" . Sometimes we give answers tha cannot be check on answerer system, that is ok WHEN clearly written w- was code tested or not

Comment: ok...I downloaded the derby jar files and added them to the libraries package and I am still getting the no suitable driver found error.

Comment: ok guys, I tried using the services tab in NetBeans to create the database and am getting a "Unable to listen on port 1527 Windows Socket Error 10106:create" error message. Derby Jar files are installed and I've used both netstat and another Windows program to try to figure out what's using\blocking that port and cannot find anything. should I just reinstall Netbeans or do you think it's a problem with windows? This computer has a problem doing windows updates as well.

Comment: After creating the data base in net beans, go to services tab, Right click on the data base created, and click connect. Then you will be connected to DB and it will be ready to accept connections on the port.

You can be able to connect to DB only if you start the server. After connecting to the DB, below it, you can see jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/..  like this. Which is the url to server. Use the displayed url in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the modified code.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class AnimalsWeek4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        Connection conn=null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        Statement s =null;
        String createTableSQL="CREATE TABLE  Animals ( "
                     +"Name VARCHAR(10),"
                     +"Type VARCHAR(10),"
                     +"Diet VARCHAR(10),"
                     +"Habitat VARCHAR(10))";
        try{
            //final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:Animals; create = true";
            final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TestDB";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
            System.out.println("Connected to DB successfully");
            final String dropTableSQL="DROP TABLE Animals";
            s = conn.createStatement();
            try{
            s.executeUpdate(dropTableSQL);
            System.out.println("Table Dropped");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception is "+e);
               // if (!e.getSQLState().equals("proper SQL-state for table does not exist"));
            }
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(createTableSQL);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Table is created!");

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error"+ ex.getMessage());
        }finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
                        if (s!=null){
                            s.close();
                        }

        }
    }

}
```